# Chef cookbook_file and template resource: how to test that source exists?

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

If I use a template resource in a recipe

```
template '/home/user1/foo' do
  source 'bar'
end
```

And I test using chefspec/rspec

```
...
expect(chef_run).to render_file('/home/user1/foo')
expect(chef_run).to create_template('/home/user1/foo')
expect(chef_run).to create_template('/home/user1/foo').with_source 'bar
...
```

All tests pass...
**even if the source template "bar" is missing from the cookbook.**

This leaves me with a cookbook that passes all the tests I can think of, but will fail when I try to run it.  Same for a cookbook_file resource.

I can see how it would be a can of worms to test all the places where the resource could look for the source file (per the ["File Specificity" section in the resource docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html#file-specificity)) but it still seems like a big hole in the test tools.

Am I overlooking a way to test for the existence of the source file, or doing something wrong at a more basic level?  Or is this just how it is, and everyone lives with it?

Comment: You're creating a `cookbook_file` but expecting chef to create `template`s? Not sure how also that fits together.

Comment: Ooops.  Confusing the issue by cross-pollinating templates and cookbook_files (since the same issue applies.)  Will clarify.  Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a little convoluted, but it works.
For this recipe fragment:

```
template '/home/user1/foo' do
  source 'bar'
end
```

When no template source file "bar" exists, this Chefspec expectation passes, despite the missing source file.

```
expect(chef_run).to render_file('/home/user1/foo')
```

But this fails with `Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound`, providing a way to test if the source exists:

```
expect(chef_run).to render_file('/home/user1/foo').with_content(/.*/)
```

Apparently, the **with_content()** method forces the source reference to be resolved so the matcher can render the file for comparison purposes.  If you don't really care about matching specific content, `/.*/` matches anything so you can still test that the source exists.

*more, in response to @ user3670408 's issue...*

Chefspec has to render the file content to a string to compare with the `.with_content()` argument  The issue seems to be that the actual cookbook file you're using is a binary file.  What's going on is probably something like this:

```
# Create a bad UTF-8 file
File.open('bad_utf8.bin', mode: 'wb') { |file| file.putc(0xfe) }
# Read contents and try to use the resulting string
File.read('bad_utf8.bin').match(/.*/)
# Result is:  ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

So in general, the `.with_content(/.*/)` trick won't work with binary cookbook files unless you do something hack-ey like catch the ArgumentError.

Comment: As seems to be often the case, when a solution is revealed, the question seems a bit trivial.   Of course testing with_content() would have to render the output using the specified template (or cookbook file, etc.)   

I suppose the confusing bit was that using to_render() without following up with with-content() did not actually test for successful rendering.